# Parsing HTML String in to ios

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad

I am parsing html tags into ios using TFHpple successfully, but here i got a small problem, 
if my HTML Tag is

```
 <div align="center">
            <b>
                <a href="/?PageName='TeacherPage'&StaffID=194121">
                    <span class="sectionheader">
                        Jessica
                        &nbsp;Cortes
                    </span>
                </a></b><BR>

                <span class="subheader">Migrant Education</span>
                <BR>

                    <img src="/images/Phone.gif" width="22" height="23"> 
                    912-367-8630
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/EmailIconSmall.gif" width="16" height="16" style="vertical-align:bottom" />
                    &nbsp; <a onclick="openme('z','/Common/Email/Email.asp?UserID=194121&SchoolID=786',417,320);return false;" href="#">Email</a>               

                <BR><BR>
                <a href="/?PageName='Teachers'&Category='Teachers'">View All Teachers</a>
                <BR><BR>
                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" class="subnavtd">
```

i am parsing it in to ios by using example: `NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div/span[@class='subheader']]";`

now in one of the HTML page there is no Tag, it has just a number like `912-367-8630` now how to call this in `NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"` this number is in above given tags

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to reform the HTML output and wrap that phone number in a tag that you can target? If not, you will probably have to grab the inner text value of a parent div and regex match for a phone number pattern in the string.